# Display hard-coded formulas after running macro

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to display formulas by clicking into the cell? I wrote multiple hardcoded formulas into vba and after I run the macro, I only get values in the cells. I want it so that after the macro runs, I can still view the formula in the cells. These are the formulas that I currently have:

```
Dim i, lastrow  As Integer
Range("a10").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row

For i = 10 To lastrow
Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("Q" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("D" & i), Sheets("20140617 Loans").Range("D:P"), 13, False)

Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("R" & i) = Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("P" & i) - Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("Q" & i)

Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("S" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("D" & i), Sheets("20140617 Loans").Range("D:H"), 5, False)

Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("T" & i) = Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("H" & i) - Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("S" & i)

Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("U" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("D" & i), Sheets("20140617 Loans").Range("D:G"), 4, False)

Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("V" & i) = Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("G" & i) - Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("U" & i)

Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("W" & i) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheets("WSO Interest").Range("H:H"), Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("D" & i), Sheets("WSO Interest").Range("S:S"))

Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("X" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("D" & i), Sheets("20140618 PNL").Range("C:N"), 12, False)

Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("Y" & i) = Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("R" & i) - Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("W" & i) - Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("T" & i) * (Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("G" & i) / 100) - Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("X" & i)
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not write the formulas in the cell. You set the value to the content on the right-side of the equality operator. Using a range object with an equality implies that you want to set the value, not the formula. To set the formula you need to specify the `Formula` property and you will have to set write the formula as you would in Excel.

eg.

```
Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("Q" & i).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP('20140618 Loans'!D" & i & ",'20140617 Loans'!D:P, 13, 0)"
```

Also, this is not part of your question but I think it would help you greatly to know about the `With` statements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/wc500chb.aspx

> By using With...End With, you can perform a series of statements on a
>   specified object without specifying the name of the object multiple
>   times. Within a With statement block, you can specify a member of the
>   object starting with a period, as if the With statement object
>   preceded it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Do you know how I could use something like that for a SUMIF function?

I tried `Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("W" & i).Formula = _
    "=SUMIF('WSO Interest'!H:H,'20140618 Loans'!D & i &, 'WSO Interest'!S:S)"`

but that was clearly wrong.

Comment: You need to unquote the string when you want to use a variable that you created in VBA. So `"...Loans'!D" & i & "..."`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.Formula` method like this:

`Sheets("20140618 Loans").Range("Q" & i).Formula = '...your formula here`

---

Note: You'll need to add quotes and format it as a formula that is calculated by the sheet not by VBA.  For example:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=1+2"
```

Comment: Hey I just tried this out doing...

`sheets("20140618 Loans").range("Q" & i).Formula = 'my formula`

but it's still giving me values. Can I confirm that all I am doing is just adding `.Formula` after every range?

Comment: Not quite, you also need to format each formula for use in the cell. @alexandreP.levasseur provided an example of what the equation could look like (in VBA) in his answer.  See if that helps clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build Strings to reflect the working formulas

For e.g. 
If you have column A values as below

[image]

Running the below macro

```
Sub FillInFormula()

Dim i, lastrow  As Integer
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
Range("B" & i) = "=sum(A" & i & ":A" & i + 1 & ")"
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Something like that

P.S. use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+` (above tab)  to see all formulas at once

Comment: Okay this worked out, but how could I incorporate it to use a Vlookup? Thanks again.

Comment: Replace right hand side("=SUM..) with what Alexandre P. Levasseur has suggested!